# Append specific number to specific position in 2D list

Tags: python-3.x, list, insert, insert-update

I am trying to append a number with another number at a specif spot in a 2D list.

```
# Create UAS database list that was displayed in the file
uas_Stock = [["CS116",1],["CS117",1],["CS118",1],["CS119",1],["CS120",1]]

# Ask user to select which UAV they want to check out.
uas_out = input("Which UAV would you like to checkout? ")

# Append stock list to show UAS is checked out
if uas_out == "CS116":
    uas_Stock.insert(0, [0])
elif uas_out == "CS117":
    uas_Stock.insert(1, [0])
elif uas_out == "CS118":
    uas_Stock.insert(2, [0])
elif uas_out == "CS119":
    uas_Stock.insert(3, [0])
elif uas_out == "CS120":
    uas_Stock.insert(4, [0])
else:
    print("That input is not a valid UAS ID in our system.")
```

Say I select CS117, it will run through the if/else statement to CS117. Then it will insert a 0 where the 1 currently is on the uas_Stock list.

It instead inserts a 0 to the CS117 part of the list instead of the 1 part. I have tried other ways to do it, but get errors like "int"object not subscriptable and such.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want, though it's not clear because you didn't post the expected result...

```
uas_Stock = [["CS116",1],["CS117",1],["CS118",1],["CS119",1],["CS120",1]]

# Ask user to select which UAV they want to check out.
uas_out = input("Which UAV would you like to checkout? ")

# Append stock list to show UAS is checked out
found = False
for stock_list in uas_Stock:
    if stock_list[0] == uas_out:
        stock_list[1] = 0
        found = True
        break
if not found:
    print("That input is not a valid UAS ID in our system.")
```

This searches through the list and changes the number to a 0 when it finds the UAS.

Sample run:

```
Which UAV would you like to checkout? CS117
>>> print(uas_Stock)
[['CS116', 1], ['CS117', 0], ['CS118', 1], ['CS119', 1], ['CS120', 1]]
```

You were *inserting* new lists into the *outer* list, while (I think) what you really wanted to do was *replace* values in the *inner* lists.